# most efficient way to create file and delete file of same name in for loop python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, operating-system

I download data from aws s3 then unzip, format data then try to send that unzipped, formatted file to aws elasticsearch.

For each file it will create it on my local computer as "access.log", delete it after unzip, formatting, send to aws elasticsearch then repeat the process.

However when I try to do this with same name it tells me that I cannot delete while working with a file, I do not want to create multiple files. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

NOTE: acc_logs is a list of many log files. ex: acc_log_file.gz

here is my code:

```
for log_file in acc_logs: # one file
    bucket.download_file(log_file, 'C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\s3-to-es\\access.log')
    with gzip.open('C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\s3-to-es\\access.log') as log_file:
        for line in log_file:
            line = line.decode("utf-8") # decode byte to str
            try:
                ip = ip_pattern.search(line).group(0)
            except:
                ip = None
            try:
                host = host_pattern.search(line).group(0)[1:-1]
            except:
                host = None

            date            = time_pattern.search(line).group(0)[1:-1]
            pos             = [x.end() for x in re.finditer('"', line)]
            request         = line[pos[0]:pos[1]-1]
            referr_url      = line[pos[2]:pos[3]-1]
            user_agent      = line[pos[4]:pos[5]-1]
            status, bytes   = line[pos[1]+1:pos[2]-2].split()
            ident, authuser = authuser_pattern.search(line).group(0).split()
            document = {"server_ip": ip,
                        "host":host, 
                        "ident":ident, 
                        "authuser":authuser, 
                        "date": date, 
                        "request":request, 
                        "status":status, 
                        "bytes":bytes,
                        "referr_url":referr_url, 
                        "user_agent":user_agent
                       }

            ToElasticSearch(document) #upload each line to es

            if count == 10:
                break

        os.remove('C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\s3-to-es\\access.log')
```

ToElasticSearch looks like:

```
def ToElasticSearch(document):
    """
      upload given document to specified index in AWS
    """
    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
    es = Elasticsearch(
        hosts = [{'host': es_host, 'port': 443}],
        http_auth = awsauth,
        use_ssl = True,
        verify_certs = True,
        connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
        )
    es.index(index="acc_logs", doc_type="_doc", body=document)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete the file while it is still open:

```py
    with gzip.open('C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\s3-to-es\\access.log') as log_file:
        for line in log_file:
            ...blah...
        os.remove('C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\s3-to-es\\access.log')
```

If you change the indent on the `os.remove()` line *outwards* one level (less spaces), the the file will not be open and it should delete just fine.